# Keeping "info" lines visible after quitting "info"?

Tags: bashrc, manpage, info

I have:

```
export MANPAGER="/usr/bin/less -r -X -is"
```

as the last line in `~/.bashrc`. This allows me to keep most of a man page visible on screen after exiting `man`.

I want to do the same when I view `info` pages. How to do so? Now, it looks like the info page is "drawn" over existing content on the terminal screen. And leaving `info` brings back the previous screen completely. What I want is to have the part of `info` I was viewing to remain on the screen with a terminal prompt as last line (for typing commands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get info for the ls command, for example, and keep it on screen after you quit, this might work:

```
env TERM=vt220 info ls
```

I don't think it will work as an alias, but you could make your own script called *info* and put it earlier in your $PATH than /usr/bin/info.

```
env TERM=vt220 /usr/bin/info "$1"
```

Comment: PS: I made this alias in `~/.bash_aliases`: `alias myinfo='env TERM=vt220 info'` and then I type `myinfo ls` to get information about `ls`. So no need of script and modifying `$PATH`. Thanks greatly :)